# Name Manager and List Data Validation Excel

Tags: excel

My [Sheet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/W652p.png)

[image]

& [Name Manager](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WbLsF.png)

[image]

I want to make a `Data Validation` that allow `List` using `Name` as in `Name Manager`.

I success in making `Data Validation` with `=ListA` & `=ListB` as the source.

But fail when using `=ListAll`, it says

> The list source must be a delimited list, or a reference to single row or column

So how do I make a list of `A+B`?

Additional Note:

- The `list` can be modified just by modifying the table in the sheet
- Unfortunately, I can't put `B` in the bottom of `A`

edit: If possible, I don't want to use VB

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without VBA you could have a helper column which can be hidden later:

[image]

Formula in `G2` downwards:

```
=IF(ROW(A1)<=$D$4,INDEX($A$2:$A$20,ROW(A1)),IF(ROW(A1)<=$D$4+$D$5,INDEX($B$2:$B$20,ROW(A1)-$D$4)))
```

Now you can have following formula for `ListAll`

```
=OFFSET(Sheet1!$G$1,1,0,Sheet1!$D$4+Sheet1!$D$5,1)
```

Comment: A little annoying that you said `Unfortunately, I can't put B in the bottom of A` when that's exactly what the accepted answer does.

Comment: My client needs A&B to be placed like that. Actually, I'm a bit hesitate for copying the cell like that (for size reason), but it seems the data is limited to 20 so I guess it's ok, and Axel's formula helps me in doing that